# Testing nodes connectivity

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, oracle-spatial

I'm working on a shapefile of Brussels (QGIS 3). This shapefile contains all the streets in Brussels, see below.

[image: example1]

With the attribute table, I have an `"X"` and `"Y"` position for each line (debut and end),

[image: example2]

I used this to create nodes at each debut and end of the line in Oracle Spatial.

[image: example3]
[image: example4]

**Now I need to check if**

- all the nodes are not in double
- They are all connected to another
- There isn't one node so close to another that a travelling test would take the wrong way

EDIT :

For now I'm just Using the network analasys from Processing Tools, and I take one node on the left and one on the right (then N and S etc) and ask for the shortest path to see if it's OK. But There should be an easiest way that provides to do an analysis on all the Network !

==> SO I'm looking for 
- a way to calculate a lot of shortest path easily (maybe with a script) or
- another way to see if each point is really connected to the rest.

Maybe I could take a point in the center and test it with all of the point on the external (like the boarder of my shp?)

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Cyril , Done !

Comment: Was your issue resolved? If yes, please put those *edits* as an answer.

Comment: @Taras No it is not, I would like to test a lot of shortest path with a script or something, I'll edit my title !

Comment: @Taras I changed title and edit again my question

Comment: Are you aware that if you ask for a script solutions your question can be easily put on hold in case if you do not show any code attempts?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that